# Change datasource location in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to use the code below in order to change datasource location in runtime;
I have a question about using this code :
Does this code changes all datasource locations of subreports of a report  ?
Tnx;

```
ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\ReportName.rpt");

ConnectionInfo crConnection = new ConnectionInfo();
crConnection.UserID = userID;
crConnection.ServerName = datasource;
crConnection.DatabaseName = "";
crConnection.Password = password;

AssignConnectionInfo(doc,crConnection);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through all subreports and Assign new connection to each subreport.